# HTMl+SVG+JavaScript: change text at runtime?

Tags: javascript, svg, prototypejs, inkscape

I am about to migrate a few Flash-based applications to HTML+JavaScript+SVG (the single target rendering engine is Webkit).

I'm completely new to SVG and I'd like to know if I can use a SVG as a template image to fill the screen and change contained text on the fly from the JavaScript code embedded in the HTML page.

What I want to do is: draw the basic structure of the page in Inkscape (with some graphics and text placeholders) and then just display the SVG in the HTML page and fill the text placeholders via JavaScript.

I *could* get the same *result* by displaying a static SVG image in the background and place some absolutely positioned DIVs on top of it to display the text, but I'd like to design the position, size and style of the text labels from within Inkscape.

Can this be done? How?

I'm using the [Prototype framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/), not JQuery.

Comment: Use html5 'inline svg' with <svg></svg>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you access the SVG depends on exactly how you include it in your page.  You can either use and `object` or `embed` element and link to the SVG, or include it inline in the page.  Note that including it via an `img` element won't work - the SVG will be treated as an image 'black box', you won't be able to access the internal structure.

Embedding via an object is straightforward and will work in all browsers which support SVG:

```
<object id="svg_object" width="672" height="243" data="myimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    No SVG support
</object>
```

Then to get at the internal structure you need to get the `contentDocument`:

```
var svg = $('svg_object').contentDocument;
var svgel = svg.getElementById('myid');
```

Note that the internal DOM of the SVG won't be automatically extended by prototype.js in this case, so you'll have to fall back on regular DOM methods.

Embedding the SVG directly in the page will work if you serve your page as `application/xhtml+xml` or if the browser has an HTML5 compliant parser (Firefox 4, Chrome, IE9 but not Opera or earlier Firefox).  However, now your prototype.js methods will work directly with the SVG elements, making certain things much more simple:

```
var svgel = $('myid');
```

I've done a couple of examples: [object](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/svg-object-javascript.html), [inline](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/svg-inline-javascript.html).  They work for me in Firefox 4, you may need to do some messing around to get them working in other browsers (with the caveats mentioned above as far as support is concerned).

Comment: Great example, thanks! FYI: The `object` example links to a local file ;)

Comment: @UdoG D'Oh!  Fixed the link now.

Answer (score 6):

Try jQuery. Set manually an ID to an SVG-TextNode, and then try:

```
$("#my_id").textContent = "new Value";
```

May be it works. Otherwise try:

```
document.getElementById("my_id").textContent = "new Value";
```

Comment: jQuery is using CSS selector within the $ function. This code sample is incorrect. $('#my_id') should be used instead. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/svg is also helpful when dealing with SVG from jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using the JQuery framework but Prototype instead (updated the description accordingly).

Comment: I'd suggest using `elm.textContent = "new Value"` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the pure JS solution, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

SVG is a XML based document, that you can manipulate with javascript just like you manipulate XHTML documents.

getElementById will work with SVG the same way it work with xhtml, so you'll be hable to change text in a SVG dynamically.

Comment: How should I access these nodes? I tried embedding the SVG by using `<img>` and `<embed>` but neither of these allow me to enter the XML tree of the SVG document (ie. there is no html_svg_dom_element.`getElementById()` and ...`getElementsByTagName()` returns an empty list.